# Cloud foundary uaa log customize

Tags: tomcat, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am running tomcat in unix machine, and deployed cloud foundary war file. By default uaa.log file is generating in tomcat logs folder.  Now the question is how to move this log file to some other location,  like /root/logs.

Here tomcat logs

```
root@linux-vm:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.26/logs# ls -lrt

-rw-r----- 1 root root       0 Dec 26 06:01 manager.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root       0 Dec 26 06:01 host-manager.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root       0 Dec 26 06:01 localhost_access_log.2019-12-26.txt
-rw-r----- 1 root root    2481 Dec 26 06:12 localhost.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root   31443 Dec 26 06:12 catalina.2019-12-26.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root  179793 Dec 26 06:24 uaa.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1042803 Dec 26 06:24 catalina.out
```

Now uaa.log file is available under the /tomcat/logs folder location, now the question is i don't want generate uaa.log file in this location, instead of this it should be some where else required.

Can you please any one help me on this.

Comment: Can you please some one help me on this issue.